# Why isn't $H_n(M) \cong 0$ for any $n$-manifold $M$ with non-trivial boundary?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I learned [here](https://www2.bc.edu/joshua-e-greene/MT885S13/Lecture%203.pdf) that if we have a connected "open manifold" $M$ of dimension $n$, then $H_n(M) \cong 0$. I'm not quite sure why this can't be used to prove that every connected $n$-manifold with non-trivial boundary has $H_n(M) \cong 0$. In particular, doesn't this mean that $M\setminus \partial M$ has trivial $n$th homology group? If so, does this imply that $M$ is not homotopy equivalent to $M \setminus \partial M$, and if not, why isn't $H_n(M)$ trivial for any $n$-manifold $M$ with non-trivial boundary?

Comment: It *is* trivial.  Who said it's not?

Comment: @MikhailKatz, no one said it's not. I just realllyyyyy didn't expect it.

Comment: Only closed manifolds have an absolute [fundamental class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_class). Of course there are relative classes also.

Comment: If $M$ is an $n$-manifold with non-trivial boundary then it is true that there is a homotopy equivalence $M\simeq M\setminus M$. You can see this by taking a collar neighbourhood $U$ of $\partial M$. $U$ is diffeomorphic to $\partial M\times [0,\infty)$ and you can get the result.

Comment: Consider $S^n \cup B^n$: that's an $n$-manifold with boundary $S^{n-1}$, but its top homology group is $\Bbb Z$. (That answers the question in your last sentence; I assume you accidentally left out the word "connected".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, for e.g singular homology, if $M$ is connected and with boundary we have $H_n(M) = 0$.

However, let me quickly mention Borel-Moore homology. The theory was made to extend Poincaré duality to more general spaces.  There is always a top class in Borel-Moore homology, for example $H^{BM}_i(\Bbb R^n) = \Bbb Z$ if $i=n$ and $0$ else (notice that it is not homotopy invariant).